# Nesting filters in dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, nested

I am trying to filter an observation first, and then use that observation to further filter the data.

Regex:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(10)

  df <- data.frame(
    nm = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )]
    ,vl = rnorm(20, 100, 1)
  )

df$prctl = cume_dist(df$vl)
```

I have done this in 2 steps, first is filtering for the observation:

```
  obs <- df %>%
    filter(nm == "M") %>%
    pull(prctl)
```

Then use the obs value to further filter:

```
  df %>%
    filter(
      between(
        x = prctl
        ,left = obs - 0.05
        ,right = obs + 0.05
      )
    )
```

This works, but I feel there could be more elegant ways to do this. Obviously I can replace obs in the last block with the actual code but that would mean the code for left and right will need to be evaluated twice.

Any elegant workarounds for this? Cheers

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility while generating random data. Also the code to generate `df` doesn't work in its current form.

Comment: @RonakShah Cheers yea I was in a hurry when I was copying and pasting the code blocks. Updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the `prctl` value in a temporary variable (to avoid evaluating the same thing twice) and use it to create `left` and `right` values for `between` to `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter({i = prctl[nm == "M"]; between(prctl, i - 0.05, i + 0.05)})
```